# How do you set the python system interpreter?

Tags: python, pycharm

Title. For the tutorial I'm trying to learn from, the instructions are to set the System Interpreter to python. So I know where I need to go to change this, but every time I select the Python interpreter tab I am prompted with the following:

[prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7S8w.jpg)

If I ignore it, it goes away after 10s.Then I select "Add Python Interpreter" and I select "System Interpreter":
[system interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jblNy.jpg)

It doesn't seem to have the desired effect though, and when I Ctrl+Shift+F10 my script I get this: [not what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnO2Q.png)

Any help boys, I'm struggling to set up Python :(

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a "system interpreter", at least on Linux or MacOS. Which platform are you on? (Note that many of us won't follow screenshot links: a question should be answerable using only its textual content).

Comment: I think the tutorial is refering to your general pyton installation. In python you often use and create virtual environments where you basically start from a clean python state

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using windows

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set up an IDE. You really need to take a look at [ask] and the [help].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What? I've scarcely heard of a version of Linux or MacOS that _doesn't_ come with a "system interpreter", at least if you go by the definition from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (venv) of "one which is installed as part of your operating system" or the colloquial one of "the interpreter associated with the 'system site packages'".

Comment: Also, in the third screen, system interpreter, click on the three dots and there should be an "add interpreter". Relevant docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: @Brian, the interpreter installed as part of the operating system is an innate part of that operating system and can't be replaced without breaking OS-vendor-provided scripts, so that definition can't be the relevant one here.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just launch the installer again and uninstall whatever python you have now. Then run the installer again and tick the "Add Python 3.X.X to PATH" box on one of the pages. This adds the python executable to system PATH variable, which allows you to run the `python` or `pip` command from anywhere on your system.

After that, Pycharm should be able to automatically detect your python installation. If not, try to relaunch Pycharm or create a new project.

If you want, you can also check out environment management tools for Python, such as [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), which comes out of the box, or [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). What these tools do is basically create a copy of your python setup in a separate venv folder and allow you to use it to run your scripts and install packages - all completely isolated from your system interpreter. When setting up an interpreter in Pycharm, there are options for both these tools (the virtual environments will be automatically created for your project).